# How do I install Gnome Classic (No Effects) only?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-minimal

If I do:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

It will include Gnome Classic WITH effects, which makes it depend on compiz and etc. That is not desirable for me, as I only want the without effects. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to install *all* of Gnome to get classic no effects.  Or at least all of classic.